# Isometry on compact metric space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and also let $f:X\longrightarrow X$ be an isometry.

> Is it necessary that $f$ is onto?

We know every Banach space can be regarded (or modeled) as $C(X)$ for some compact space $X$.

> Can we model all compact metric spaces?

Answer (score 1):

As for your first question, the answer is **yes**: take any $x\in X$
and consider the sequence $x_n:=f^{(n)}(x)$. 
By compactness there is a converging subsequence $x_{n_k}\to \overline{x}$,
so for some $k$ we have
$$d(f^{(n_k)}(x),f^{(n_{k+1})}(x))<\epsilon$$
and since $f$ is an isometry we get
$$d(x,f^{(n_{k+1}-n_k)}(x))=d(f^{(n_k)}(x),f^{(n_{k+1})}(x))<\epsilon$$
But $f^{(n_{k+1}-n_k)}(x)\in f(X)$, so we have deduced that $d(x,f(X))<\epsilon$
for any $\epsilon$.
Thus $d(x,f(X))=0$, but $f(X)$ is compact, hence closed, so $x\in f(X)$ and $f$ is surjective.

As for the second question, Banach-Mazur theorem tells you that every Banach space can be thought of as a closed (linear) **subspace** of some $C(X)$, not as the whole $C(X)$. 
The same is true for any compact space $X$ (of course linearity has no meaning here). There is a standard construction to embed $X$ in $C(X)$ as follows: fix some $x_0\in X$ and associate to any
$x\in X$ the function $f_x:X\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_x(y):=d(y,x)-d(y,x_0)$$
Then the map $X\to C(X)$, $x\mapsto f_x$ is a continuous embedding (why?).